# How to download on demand video courses

Tags: video, video-capture, flash, download

I don't always have access to the internet when traveling so I am trying to see if I can save everything locally.

The videos are launched in a new popup window (the whole window is flash b/c if I right click on it, it'll only gives me the flash menu).

- Can't use chrome plugins b/c they do not come up on the popup window.
- wget command on Linux failed
- curl -o [what I want to call it] [their url] command also failed
- Only thing I see I'm left with is screen capture but with that I have to go through all of the videos (they are slide style videos and there is A LOT of them) and let them play one by one. And it won't save anything from the note tabs or the resource tabs (I would like to get those as well but could live without).

Any solution to this? The videos are being hosted by geolearning